# How to draw a block diagram with TiKz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

Can you help me about drawing a block diagram with TiKz, I want draw it similar to this[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners},
forked edges,
[text [text [text][text]][text [text][text][text]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Help me! Using with package MathTime Professional 2 (MTPro2) fonts, they are not working...error!

Comment: @LêTrườngEm This problem is not related with your original question. Please make a new one, if possible with a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)